# titanium android module native view creation

Tags: view, native, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules, create-view

**java script to access module**

```js
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            backgroundColor : 'white'

        });


        Ti.API.info("module is => " + module);

        var proxy = module.createExample({
            height : '200dp',
            pdfurl:"http://10.1.2.38:8080/ls/DOWNLOAD/ex.pdf",
            lckey:"XXXXXX",
            backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF'
        });

        proxy.showPdfBy(pdfurl);
        win.add(proxy);

        win.open();
```

**java code**

```java
@Override
    public TiUIView createView(Activity activity) {
        R.string.text_ok = ResUtil.instance().getResId("string", "text_ok",
                getActivity());

        **String url =  activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("pdfurl");**

        AppLog.errorLog("backgroundColor ---||------ = " +url );
        TiUIView view = new PdfTiView(this);
        view.getLayoutParams().autoFillsHeight = true;
        view.getLayoutParams().autoFillsWidth = true;
        return view;
    }
```

I want to get the `pdfurl` string (set in JavaScript) on java code (instead of String url).  Currently it is `null`.

Comment: i got the solution :- 

KrollDict inputs = view.getProxy().getProperties();
String pdf_url = inputs.getString("PDF_URL");

Comment: If you've found the correct solution, post it as an answer to your own question.  Then you can select it as the correct answer and the community can rate it.